# Place div first in DOM, but last on rendered page

Tags: html

I want to place a div at top of page source. When users visit page they will see this `div` at bottom of page.

For example:
When you open page you will see as below

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
some text
```

But page source will be shown as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="top">Some text</div> 
     <p>aaaa</p>
     <p>bbbb</p>
     <p>cccc</p>
     
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you make executable snippet ?

Comment: Only want to display purpose or change DOM order as well?

Comment: I want to show it as at bottom for users but on page source will be shown as at top of page

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for JavaScript or jQuery to achieve this. Only some CSS `flexbox` is needed to achieve this. See this small example that puts the `div` with class `top` as the last child of the body, while it remains as the first item in the page source.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.top {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Bottom</div>
  <div>Block 1</div>
  <div>Block 2</div>
  <div>Block 3</div>
</div>
```